# No usages found in module in Goland

Tags: go, intellij-idea, package, goland

I'm using struct from subpackage and it works. But on find usage of this structure IDEA doesn't see usages. The same situation on rename for the structure - IDEA renames the original structure and doesn't rename it in all places of usage.
How can I fix it, because I don't want to put all go files only in one package.

[image]

Comment: Have you set GOPATH? Does it work if you don't use relative imports (e.g. github.com/user/structs instead of ./structs)?

Comment: You need to provide more details as the question is incomplete. Is this IDEA or GoLand? Which version? How is the project structured? Is there a way to reproduce this? Can you open a ticket on the official tracker, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go , with more details?

Comment: @Peter, GOPATH was global. When I created /src folder, put all code in /src and changed GOPATH on packagetester folder, then idea found all usages.

Comment: @dlsniper, it works now when I'm using not global GOPATH, but GOPATH for project (or module) and with /src folder. I don't like this solution (I want to use global GOPATH). Thats why I'll ask question on youtrack.jetbrains. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go project directory like this.

```
projectname:
  bin/
  src/
     structs/
        custom_types.go
     main.go
  pkg/
```

Use go build command will auto create bin/pkg directory.
src directory contains all go source files.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added in my structure src/ folder and changed GOPATH (on packagetester folder) and it works now.

Comment: I updated Goland to the last 2018.1 EAP and it works now with global GOPATH and without src folder.